# add closing tag at end of line using notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, xml

I have a text document where every line has an opening tag. I need to add a matching closing tag at the end of each line.

For example:

What I have:`<exe>Example text between tags.`

What I need:`<exe>Example text between tags.</exe>`

I am new to "Find & Replace" in Notepad++ but I've had some success formatting this document to my needs. Can someone provides some guidance/tips?

Comment: Does every line have an opening tag at the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will put a matching closing tag at the end of every line. Go to search/replace and choose regex as the search mode.

```
Find what: ^<(.+)>(.+)$
Replace with: <\1>\2</\1>
```

The `find what` looks for the opening tag at the beginning of the line, and stores it in `\1`, and puts the rest of the line in `\2`

We then create the new line in the `replace` using `\1` for the opening and closing tags, and `\2` for the content in between.